# vars.get command in groovy verification - jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

In documentation mentioned that to see/pass variable content we should use

```
var2 = vars.get("var1");
```

I created a script and tried to use this get function and the value is `null`, when I printed the value of the "source" variable I see its value, can someone please explain? (as you can see when I print using get I see `NULL` returned)

Moreover can someone please fully explained (with PIC if I may ask) how to call `var2` in a second sampler, I am facing an issues with variables in groovy and read the DOCs

[image: documantation]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vars.get` can handle only String and not other objects as Integer,

You need to put the value of Integer using `putObject`, First groovy:

```
def old_budget = 137000000
vars.putObject("old_budget", old_budget);
```

You need to put the value of Integer using `getObject`, Second groovy:

```
def old_budget = vars.getObject("old_budget");
log.info(String.valueOf(old_budget));
```

Answer (score 2):

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for all available methods and fields.

If your `var1` is not null and it is a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) you code should work normally. Demo:

[image: JMeter JSR223 Accessing Variables]

In case of any problems check out *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries, you should be able to figure out the cause of your Groovy script failure from there.

Going forward always include your full code as well as the relevant jmeter.log file entries, preferably in form of text, not images.

See [Groovy Getting Started](http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html#gettingstarted) and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guides for more information on Groovy scripting in general and in the context of JMeter scripts.